# Use FFMPEG to record a RTSP stream to a local file

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, stream, record, libav

I'm looking for a snippet (C/ObjC) in which an up-to-date version of FFMPEG is used to capture a RTSP or RTP stream and save it as a .mp4 file onto the device (with a start/stop record button)

Almost all snippets are are out-dated. I would like to use FFMPEG/Libav v3.2-v3.4

I'm using [IJKPlayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer) to display the streams, which works nicely, but there's no record functionality included.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ffmpeg call from a command line. Ffmpeg syntax is very straight forward.

```
ffmpeg [global_options] {[input_file_options] -i input_url} ... {[output_file_options] output_url} ...
```

So, if you don´t need to reencode or decode your RTPS video stream, you can simply run:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://your_stream_url your_file_name.format
```

Where format could be avi, mp4, flv or others, ffmpeg you automatic package your stream to the output file.

More information here.

https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: This records a file but it's not playable as that format with ffplay.  e.g. with ffmpeg/fplay version 4.4.3 (Debian) and -i rtsp://.. foo.mp4  it complains "[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7faddc000cc0] moov atom not found0/0".

Answer (score 0):

my demo:
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.100:554/h264/ch1/main/av_stream" -f segment -segment_time 5 %d.mp4

Comment: Could you explain your answer a little bit, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://video.example.com:8554/path_to_stream -c copy outfile.mp4
```

It appears that the magic sauce is `-c copy`.  For example, if I try to record to mp4 without `-c copy`, data is written to disk, but attempting to play it with ffplay results in the error:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7faddc000cc0] moov atom not found0/0   
outfile.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

This is with:

```
ffplay version 4.4.3 Copyright (c) 2003-2022 the FFmpeg developers
```

I noticed this from [this repo](https://github.com/Path-Variable/recording-scripts/blob/master/record.sh) and iterated down to a working base case.